# Best design pattern to instantiate multiple instances of a class with unity framework

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, factory-pattern

I generally try with dependency injection frameworks to use constructor injection, and to avoid injecting the Container to my classes. However, I need to create multiple instances (one per processing thread) of a message processor, so I can't use constructor injection to instantiate those processors.

Of course I can inject the container and resolve the processors using that, but many say that's an anti-pattern. I can alternatively create a factory for them, resolve the factory, and use that to construct the processors. But having to have a separate factory for each type I'd want to inject, even though no parameters are required to construct the type correctly, seems like a lot of overhead, so I'm inclined to just inject the container instead of that... Do others have thoughts on the best way to handle this scenario?

Many thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Did you try to inject `Func<IMessageProcessor>`? Unity knows how to inject `Func<T>` if `T` is registered. Can you provide some code to show how you create a message processor for each thread?

Comment: Thanks! This is working for me, creating a factory that constructs an IMessageProcessor without me having to declare a custom factory class! Unfortunately, since this is entered as a comment I don't think I can mark it as solution, but this has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The anti-pattern you are referring to is called [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Whether or not the dependency on the container is a form of Service Location depends on where you use it. This is because Service Locator is about [the role, not about the mechanics](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/). So you are free to use the container for all code that is located inside your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Although it is fine to use the container to create instances for you on the fly, it is generally [bad to have application-accessible factory abstractions](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) that create components, since:

> Service abstractions should not expose other service abstractions in their definition

Instead, if such message processer needs to be created on the fly, this is not a concern of the consumer; creating an extra abstraction just complicates your code. So instead you want to create a proxy implementation for your message processors (defined in your Composition Root) that calls back into the container at runtime to create a transient message processor implementation for you. You inject that proxy into the consumers instead of the real message processor, and since both the proxy and the real processor implement the same interface, the consumer doesn't know about this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I'm a bit confused regarding the suggestion - if you truly mean to declare a proxy class at the composition root, I see how that could substitute for my message processor class, but how would that help me to create the multiple instances I need? The Func<IMessageProcessor> format from the comment above does seem to allow me to create the needed factory on the fly without having to manually declare it - is there a reason that isn't a good solution? Many thanks!

Comment: @user756366 There is nothing wrong with using the Func<T>, but you shouldn't inject this Func into application components directly because of the reasons given above and in the referenced article. Instead you should hide this Func behind the proxy implementation. If you have to create many proxy implementations, you are missing some common abstraction in your code base.

Comment: Thanks!  I may be beginning to understand... I think you're saying I'd need to expose one MessageProcessingController instead of multiple IMessageProcessors to the consumer, with just a DTO (or Command) seen by the consumer. The controller could create IMessageProcessors internally. This resolves my issue as I can actually move the IMessageProcessor logic into the Controller. However, if I still needed the Container in the Controller, I am still confused on how the Controller would be constructed - Are you saying to bypass Unity and instantiate the controller manually?

Comment: @user756366 can you update your question with some actual code that explains your exact design. At least show the abstractions, a message processor implementation and how a controller interacts with this all. Using this information I'll be able to give much more specific feedback.